# Comparing and converting string to dates in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to select entries in the table which have values in Column1 > than in Column2. The problem is both column types are strings, however I need to convert them to dates. Column1 has a format of mm/yy and Column2 has a format of dd/mm/yy. I tried using convert:

```
SELECT * 
FROM database 
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, Column1) > CONVERT(datetime, Column2)
```

However I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: You should also check your data individually by first seeing if there are issues converting column1 and then checking the same on column2. They could both have invalid data or the conversion could fail on both but knowing that will help you figure out where you need to change the code.

Comment: They both fail. And I am using ODBC with python pyodbc

Comment: ODBC is just an API, which passes the SQL to the dbms.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following:

```
Convert(varchar(10), Column1, 101) as Date
```

`101` is a format for the date.
See this [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/) for other formats.

For your example, it would be something like this:

```
SELECT othercolumns, Convert(varchar(10), Column1, 101) as Date1, Convert(varchar(10), Column2, 101) as Date2
FROM database 
WHERE Date1 > Date2
```